# Open navigation page within Mopup window in .NET Maui

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I am programming an app with .NET Maui and use Mopup Nuget package. A pop up window should be opened and from there a navigation page should be opened by a button.  Unfortunately when clicking the button no navigation page appears. Only when I close the mopup window the navigation page is displayed.  But if I close the pop-up window first, as I was told, the navigation page is not displayed. How can I solve this? Thank you very much

```
using Mopups.Services;
using Mopups.Pages;

namespace FinanceTracker.Pages;

public partial class ExpenseEntryWindow : PopupPage
{
    public ExpenseEntryWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void btnAbbrechen_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();    
    }


    private async void btnNavigation_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage1());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should invoke both the closure of the Mopup and the navigation

```
private async void btnNavigation_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();    
    await Application.Current.MainPage?.Navigation?.PushAsync(new NewPage1());
}
```

Let me know if you have any further queries

Comment: Hey Ali. Thank you for the answer. The problem is when I close the mopup window i can not open the navigation page. Maybe because the navigation page start from the mopup. I dont know

Comment: You used the code I just gave you and it did not work?